# Overrriding Magento Block and Template

Tags: magento

I'm trying to override the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price_Template block and template with new ones provided in my module, overriding the block was ok by setting the config:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_price>ABC_PriceX_Block_Price</product_price>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

And the new block gets called

```
<?php

class ABC_PriceX_Block_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price_Template {

    protected function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();

        Mage::log('I am in ABC block');
        $this->setTemplate('pricex/price.phtml');


        Mage::log('Template file is '. $this->getTemplateFile() );
    }

}
```

However I'm getting a very weird behavior, the price block doesnt show up anymore on the front end, and all i get in the log file is

```
2012-09-07T18:05:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): I am in ABC block
2012-09-07T18:05:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): Template file is
```

And the template is not rendered:

```
<p>
<?php Mage::log('I am in ABC template'); ?>
</p>
```

Am i missing something here?

Comment: note that extending Mage_Core_Block_Template instead  of Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price_Template shows the old price template 'frontend\base\default\template\catalog/product/price.phtml' with the new block ABC_PriceX_Block_Price which is even weirder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't mention Magento versions, **but** in a vanilla install of Magento 1.7.0.1, the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price_Template` class is, despite its misleading name, **not** a template block class.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Price/Template.php
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price_Template extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    ...
}
```

Notice that it extends from `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` and not `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.

So, since it's a block you can set a template

```
$this->setTemplate('pricex/price.phtml');
```

but that's just the block's magic `get` and `set` methods working.  Similarly, when you call `getTemplateFile` Magento returns null because no one's called `setTemplateFile` yet on your block. (as opposed to a block that inherits from `Mage_Core_Block_Template`, which actually has a defined `getTemplateFile` method.

Your main problem is you're treating `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price_Template` as a template block when it's not a template block.  This is backed up by the Layout Update XML code for the same block

```
<block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template" />
```

Comment: whats a template/non-template block? all was mentioned on magento sites are structural and content block

Comment: A template block is a block that uses a <code>phtml</code> template to render its contents.  A non template block is a block that uses it's _toHtml method to render a template, and has been inserted into the layout for other reasons.

Comment: Good answer - always wondered why I could not grep price.phtml!